# PDO Query Variable Issue?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

In the following queries, I'm using entry_id values to from exp_relationships to find out the smallest value (a year) in exp_channel_data. I'll give you some dummy data.

entry_id 1 has a year of 2014
entry_id 2 has a year of 2012

The first query generates "1, 2" which I save for the next one to provide the WHERE parameters. If I were to type in "1, 2" instead of :showid, it works correctly and displays the 2012 since that is the first one in the ORDER BY I have set. But when the query runs as it is written below, it displays the 2014.

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM exp_relationships WHERE child_id = :entry_id AND grid_field_id IN (90, 91)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$showid = "";

try {
    $stmt->execute(array('entry_id' => {entry_id}));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $showid .= $row['parent_id'].", ";
    }
    $showid = substr($showid, 0, -2);
} catch(PDOException $e) { error_log($e->getMessage(),0); }

$sql = 'SELECT field_id_16 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE entry_id IN (:showid) ORDER BY field_id_16 ASC LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$year = "";

try {
    $stmt->execute(array('showid' => $showid));
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $year = $row['field_id_16'];
        echo $year;
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) { error_log($e->getMessage(),0); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because defaultly it will cast $showid to its primitive type, string or int. In you case I guess if will be the string `1, 2`. This way you cannot just inject variable value in `IN` to simulate more than one value. Each placeholder is one value, and `IN (:placeholder)` will refer to only one thing. You need either to split as much placeholders as needed, i.e. in this particular case 2 placeholders `IN (?, ?)` and then implode your `$showid` string into array. Or implode `$showid` into array and then split it into the `IN` clause, which I consider the worse way of both.